# Calculate time based metrics(hourly)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

How would I calculate time-based metrics (hourly average) based on log file data?

let me make this more clear, consider a log file that contains entries as follows: Each UIDs appears only twice in the log. they will be in embeded xml format. And they will likely appear OUT of sequence. And the log file will have data for only one day so only one day records will be there.

No of UIDs are 2 millions in log file.

I have to find out average hourly reponse time for these requests. Below has request and response in log file. UID is the key to relate b/w request and response.

```
2013-04-03 08:54:19,451 INFO  [Logger] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><log-event><message-time>2013-04-03T08:54:19.448-04:00</message-time><caller>PCMC.common.manage.springUtil</caller><body>&lt;log-message-body&gt;&lt;headers&gt;&amp;lt;FedDKPLoggingContext id="DKP_DumpDocumentProperties" type="context.generated.FedDKPLoggingContext"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;logFilter&amp;gt;7&amp;lt;/logFilter&amp;gt;&amp;lt;logSeverity&amp;gt;255&amp;lt;/logSeverity&amp;gt;&amp;lt;schemaType&amp;gt;PCMC.MRP.DocumentMetaData&amp;lt;/schemaType&amp;gt;&amp;lt;UID&amp;gt;073104c-4e-4ce-bda-694344ee62&amp;lt;/UID&amp;gt;&amp;lt;consumerSystemId&amp;gt;JTR&amp;lt;/consumerSystemId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;consumerLogin&amp;gt;jbserviceid&amp;lt;/consumerLogin&amp;gt;&amp;lt;logLocation&amp;gt;Beginning of Service&amp;lt;/logLocation&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/fedDKPLoggingContext&amp;gt;&lt;/headers&gt;&lt;payload&gt;  
&amp;lt;ratedDocument&amp;gt;  
    &amp;lt;objectType&amp;gt;OLB_BBrecords&amp;lt;/objectType&amp;gt;  
    &amp;lt;provider&amp;gt;JET&amp;lt;/provider&amp;gt;  
    &amp;lt;metadata&amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;BooleanQuery&amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;Clause   occurs=&amp;amp;quot;must&amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;TermQuery   fieldName=&amp;amp;quot;RegistrationNumber&amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;gt;44565153050735751&amp;amp;lt;/TermQuery&amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;/Clause&amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;/BooleanQuery&amp;amp;gt;&amp;lt;/metadata&amp;gt;  
&amp;lt;/ratedDocument&amp;gt;  
&lt;/payload&gt;&lt;/log-message-body&gt;</body></log-event>

2013-04-03 08:54:19,989 INFO  [Logger] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><log-event><message-time>2013-04-03T08:54:19.987-04:00</message-time><caller>PCMC.common.manage.springUtil</caller><body>&lt;log-message-body&gt;&lt;headers&gt;&amp;lt;fedDKPLoggingContext id="DKP_DumpDocumentProperties" type="context.generated.FedDKPLoggingContext"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;logFilter&amp;gt;7&amp;lt;/logFilter&amp;gt;&amp;lt;logSeverity&amp;gt;255&amp;lt;/logSeverity&amp;gt;&amp;lt;schemaType&amp;gt;PCMC.MRP.DocumentMetaData&amp;lt;/schemaType&amp;gt;&amp;lt;UID&amp;gt;073104c-4e-4ce-bda-694344ee62&amp;lt;/UID&amp;gt;&amp;lt;consumerSystemId&amp;gt;JTR&amp;lt;/consumerSystemId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;consumerLogin&amp;gt;jbserviceid&amp;lt;/consumerLogin&amp;gt;&amp;lt;logLocation&amp;gt;Successful Completion of    Service&amp;lt;/logLocation&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/fedDKPLoggingContext&amp;gt;&lt;/headers&gt;&lt;payload&gt;0&lt;/payload&gt;&lt;/log-message-body&gt;</body></log-event>
```

here is the bash script I wrote.

```
uids=cat $i|grep "Service" |awk 'BEGIN {FS="lt;";RS ="gt;"} {print $2;}'| sort -u
for uid in ${uids}; do  
    count=`grep "$uid" test.log|wc -l`
    if [ "${count}" -ne "0" ]; then
        unique_uids[counter]="$uid"
        let counter=counter+1   
    fi   
done


echo ${unique_uids[@]}   
echo $counter  
echo " Unique No:" ${#unique_uids[@]}
echo uid StartTime EndTime" > $log

for unique_uids in ${unique_uids[@]} ; do
    responseTime=`cat $i|grep "${unique_uids}" |awk '{split($2,Arr,":|,"); print Arr[1]*3600000+Arr[2]*60000+Arr[3]*1000+Arr[4]}'|sort -n`
    echo $unique_uids $responseTime >> $log
done
```

And the output should be like this
Operation comes from id, Consumer comes from documentmetadata and hour is the time 08:54:XX
So if we have more than one request and response then need to average of the response times for requests came at that hour.

Operation                   Consumer HOUR Avg-response-time(ms)
DKP_DumpDocumentProperties   MRP     08      538

Comment: How about using a more powerful tool, say, Python? Doing this with `awk`/`sed`/`bash`/… is a bit crazy, IMHO…

Comment: I don't see the response time.  is that the `989`,`389`?  But you can just use two arrays of 24 length.  One to do the sum, one to do the count.

Comment: I have not worked on python, do you have anything in python for this.

Comment: @greedybuddha The response time is the difference of two timestamps, obviously.

Comment: first column is date and 2nd is time 2013-04-03 08:54:19,989

Comment: It would help to have a desired output to make it more clear.

Comment: @fedorqui Pretty clear. Each guid is contained in the file twice. Find it's second occurence, find its first occurence, subtract. Desired output: `GUID — difference`.

Comment: And the GUID value is...?

Comment: @random_thoughts your question really sounds like “I don't know Python please, write me some code”. That's not really a good question for SO, you probably should hire a programmer.

Comment: @fedorqui There it is, in the event body.

Comment: Ohh yes i did write but my intention was diff. I have done some scripting in bash but python is completly new so anything in python would sound like this.

Comment: This is simple text processing, you don't need Python for that, it's the one and only thing that awk was invented to do and does very well. It's throwing in all those other shell tools and constructs that's making your code such a mess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your posted input file:

```
$ cat file
2013-04-03 08:54:19,989 INFO [LOGGER] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><event><body>&amp;lt;UId&amp;gt;904c-be-4e-bbda-3e62&amp;lt;/UId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;</body></event>
2013-04-03 08:54:39,389 INFO [LOGGER] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><event><body>&amp;lt;UId&amp;gt;904c-be-4e-bbda-3e62&amp;lt;/UId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;</body></event>
2013-04-03 08:54:34,979 INFO [LOGGER] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><event><body>&amp;lt;UId&amp;gt;edfc-fr-5e-bced-3443&amp;lt;/UId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;</body></event>
2013-04-03 08:55:19,569 INFO [LOGGER] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><event><body>&amp;lt;UId&amp;gt;edfc-fr-5e-bced-3443&amp;lt;/UId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;</body></event>
```

This GNU awk script (you are using GNU awk since you set RS to a multi-character string in the script you posted in your question)

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    date = $1
    time = $2
    guid = gensub(/.*;gt;([^&]+).*/,"\\1","")

    print guid, date, time
}
```

will pull out what I THINK is the information you care about:

```
$ gawk -f tst.awk file
904c-be-4e-bbda-3e62 2013-04-03 08:54:19,989
904c-be-4e-bbda-3e62 2013-04-03 08:54:39,389
edfc-fr-5e-bced-3443 2013-04-03 08:54:34,979
edfc-fr-5e-bced-3443 2013-04-03 08:55:19,569
```

The rest is simple math, right? And do it in this awk script - don't go piping the awk output to some goofy shell loop!

Comment: Thanks Ed, I am trying to understand how gensub works, will comment if it helped

Comment: Ed, one ques - My log file has some lines which are not required. How do I filter them, or to be more clear I need lines with UID on them

Comment: cat test.log |grep INFO| awk -f tst.awk > uid.log

Comment: Update your question to show your real, representative input and expected output. It's not clear fromyour comments what you want, e.g. do you want to select lines that only contain the word INFO or lines that fit some pattern that describes a UID or something else? For gensub() - it basically works like sed, read the man page http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions.

Comment: added the request and response from the log file

Comment: How would I use below awk script to work on lines which has INFO word.

Comment: Put `/INFO/` in front of the `{`.

Answer (score 3):

Extending [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17068885/970195) solution:

### Content of script.awk

```
function parse_time (date, time,        newtime) {
    gsub(/-/, " ", date)
    gsub(/:/, " ", time)
    gsub(/,.*/, "", time)
    newtime = date" "time
    return newtime
}

(gensub(/.*;gt;([^&]+).*/,"\\1","") in starttime) {
    etime = parse_time($1, $2)
    endtime[gensub(/.*;gt;([^&]+).*/,"\\1","")] = etime
    next
}
{
    stime = parse_time($1, $2)
    starttime[gensub(/.*;gt;([^&]+).*/,"\\1","")] = stime
}

END {
    for (x in starttime) {
        for (y in endtime) {
            if (x==y) {
                diff = mktime(endtime[x]) - mktime(starttime[y])
                diff = sprintf("%dh:%dm:%ds",diff/(60*60),diff%(60*60)/60,diff%60)
                print x, diff
                delete starttime[x]
                delete endtime[y]
             }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test: Modified the order of guid for testing

```
$ cat log.file 
2013-04-03 08:54:19,989 INFO [LOGGER] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><event><body>&amp;lt;UId&amp;gt;904c-be-4e-bbda-3e62&amp;lt;/UId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;</body></event>
2013-04-03 08:54:34,979 INFO [LOGGER] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><event><body>&amp;lt;UId&amp;gt;edfc-fr-5e-bced-3443&amp;lt;/UId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;</body></event>
2013-04-03 08:54:39,389 INFO [LOGGER] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><event><body>&amp;lt;UId&amp;gt;904c-be-4e-bbda-3e62&amp;lt;/UId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;</body></event>
2013-04-03 08:55:19,569 INFO [LOGGER] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><event><body>&amp;lt;UId&amp;gt;edfc-fr-5e-bced-3443&amp;lt;/UId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;</body></event>
$ awk -f script.awk log.file 
904c-be-4e-bbda-3e62 0h:0m:20s
edfc-fr-5e-bced-3443 0h:0m:45s
```

Comment: Thanks Jaypal! I am trying to understand AWK gensub, I have observed that my log file have nested xmls. will get back to you if it worked.

Comment: another condition is: these uids should be in pair to tell that requests are complete. if only one uid is there in log, I dont want response time for that.

Comment: Jaypal, Is there any way we can compute response time in miliseconds. 08:54:19.989 here 989 is in miliseconds.